# How to access the advanced boot options before/during Windows 10 boots up

Tags: boot, windows-10, external-display, display-settings

I have recently been messing around with a second monitor and the system's display settings and now, every time I try to boot up, the screen goes completely black (not even a mouse cursor) right after Windows 10 finishes booting. All the guides I've read only explain how to access the advanced boot options menu once booted up, therefore rendering themselves useless to me.

As a side question: how do I change my display settings without booting Windows? What I did was add a second monitor and chose to extend the screen to it right before accidentally turning my PC off with the power button.

Comment: How do you expect to get a quality answer when you can't even spellcheck your question?

Comment: Can you understand the question?

Answer (score 0):

When windows 10 boots, it is supposed to be on the Login and User Select screen: press Win + P and move with arrows up or down and press enter to change from "Second Screen Only" to -> "PC Screen Only", -> "Dupliate" -> and "Extend". You must have the "Second Screen Only" option. Just press Win + P and select any of the other 3 options and your monitor should be enabled now

Comment: Nope, didnt work.